# How to make my custom "fungible" token appear with logo on Solflare?

Tags: solflare, fungible-token, metaplex

The Solana Token List is now archived.
So I tried adding the token metadata to metaplex.

Here's what I uploaded:

```
{
  "description":"Fake USDC for testing.",
  "image":"<url of my fake usdc logo>",
  "name":"Fake USD Coin",
  "symbol":"FUSDC"
}
```

It shows up correctly on the Phantom wallet.
But it shows up as an NFT (Collectible) on the Solflare wallet.

How do we add custom tokens to solflare?

Answer (score 6):

You did everything correctly, Solflare doesn't show those tokens correctly yet but we have a fix that should be live tomorrow probably :)

Answer (score 2):

This might be one for Solflare support: https://solflare.com/support

They document that they support the NFT standard from metaplex: https://docs.solflare.com/solflare/technical/our-nft-standard but they don't mention fungible tokens as far as I can see. I know that in the past they have had great support using token-list, but as you said that's deprecated now. So probably best to reach out to them and see if they support fungible tokens using the metaplex standard, or just NFTs.